# Geographic maps in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, openstreetmap

I have OSM data in SHP format inside ArcMap 10. But in ArcMap they are stretched a lot East-West compared to what I see at www.openstreetmap.org. How can I change it in ArcMap? I am not looking for transforming the lat/long coordinates.

MapInfo also shows the same SHP file like OSM do it.

Comment: which area (data coverage) do you have your shapefile for?

Comment: I am not aware of any projected systems that measure the x different from the y. So either your data has been re-projected in correctly or you are looking at lat lon.

Comment: It is unprojected lat/long data (as already stated). Coverage can be any area supported by OSM = the whole world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, MapInfo uses equidistant cylindrical and sets the standard parallel to match the center of the display. It's dynamic as the display is panned or zoomed. ArcGIS Business Analyst does something similar.

Comment: That sounds correct. If ArcMap doesn't have a similar feature, I just have to stick to MapInfo as much as possible (which I do anyway). It has just always annoyed me, that ArcMap shows lat/long data in such a distorted fashion compared to what you know from any printed map of the same area. Lets hope ESRI adds this feature to ArcMap if it already exists in Business Analyst.

Comment: I've argued against this in the past. Equidistant cylindrical isn't always the most appropriate map projection. If a software package is setting a coordinate system behind the scenes, and you then make a map, how are going to add appropriate metadata to the map document?

Answer (score 2):

if you right click the very top level in the table of contents. choose the layers> and then properties. change the coordinate system in the dialog to a local system.

Comment: But this requires that I know a relevant local system. If my dataset is big enough, there may be no single local system at all. MapInfo does this automatically. No questions asked.

Comment: @Uffe What projection does MapInfo automatically apply, then?

Comment: arcmap applies the projection (or gcs) of the first layer encountered when data is added. In the case that you select more than one layer to add at the same time. if you only add one layer then it applies that layers system.